# Definition and etymology of 'disingratiate'

Tags: meaning, etymology

In Bradbury's story 'The Burning Man' I found:

> In just two minutes of leaping into the red-hot car, with his jungle hair and jungle smell, he had managed to **disingratiate** himself with the climate, the automobile, Doug, and the honorable and perspiring aunt.

The term `disingratiate` is unknown to the Oxford dictionary and merely defined by the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=disingratiate%20)

Why is this?

Comment: It's just "dis-" + "ingratiate" (oneself); are you familiar with the latter word?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have room to include all the words that can be formed with common prefixes like "un-," "anti-," "non-" and "dis-".

Comment: Expanding @sumelic's explanation just a bit, if the prefix + root has an unexpected meaning, or multiple meanings, you will likely find them defined. An example of the first case is *invaluable* which usually is used in the sense of "so valuable it cannot be priced", rather than the expected "without value", or worthless. An example of the second case is the word *invalid*, which besides meaning "having no validity", also means (at least in US English) someone who is physically disabled.

Comment: ***Ingratiate (v.)***: 
1620s, possibly via 16c. Italian ingraziarsi "to bring (oneself) into favor," from Latin in gratiam "for the favor of," from in "in" (see in- (2)) + gratia "favor, grace" (see grace).  ***Dis-*** (assimilated as dif- before -f-, to di- before most voiced consonants), ***word-forming element meaning 1. "lack of, not" (as in dishonest);***  2. "do the opposite of" (as in disallow); 3. "apart, away" (as in discard), from Old French des-. (Etymonline)

Comment: It's a funny word, used in a funny passage.

Comment: WHICH Oxford Dictionary?

Comment: @Margana where lies its funny note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Burning Man---he of the jungle hair and jungle smell---had once found favor "*with the climate, the automobile, Doug, and the honorable and perspiring aunt*", as a result of his “crazy talk”---mostly about the heat and it’s unbearability---the Burning Man had managed to decisively reverse his fortune.

> [**ingratiate**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ingratiate&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=define+ingratiate&gs_l=hp..2.0l2j0i7i30j0l2.0.0.7.817743...........0.-dvP2_SP8IU&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: bring oneself into favor with someone by flattering or trying to please them. "a social climber who had tried to *ingratiate* herself with the city gentry"
>
> ***synonyms***: curry favor with, cultivate, win over, get in good with; see, Google
>
> [**ingratiate**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ingratiate&searchmode=nl) (*v*.) 1620s, possibly via 16c. Italian *ingraziarsi* "to bring (oneself) into favor," from Latin *in gratiam* "for the favor of," from in "*in*" (see in- (2)) + *gratia* "favor, grace" (see grace). See, etymonline
>
> [**disfavor**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=disfavor+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=disfavor+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i22i30l4.0.0.6.677089...........0.OROoHbzmozk&gws_rd=ssl) *noun*: 1. disapproval or dislike. "the headmaster regarded her with disfavor"
>
> ***synonyms***: disapproval, disapprobation; see, Google